# How to redirect two different users to different activity after login using firebase auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating an android application using the Firebase authentication and database.
For my app I need to identify the users after they logged in and redirect them to two different activities. (admin/simple user)
In my app I have only 10-20 users all time, and there isn't a way to register, it's a company only app.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If max users you expect is 20 then why would you need a authentication usage ( Google, Facebook ) etc. Have a simple database entry for all users as follows:

{
  "app_title": "YourApp",
  "users": {
    "-KTYWvZG4Qn9ZYTc47O6": {
      "username": "pkondedath",
      "useremail": "hello@kondedath.com",
      "password" : "hello123"
      "userpic": "example.com/a.png",
      "prevelidge" : "superuser"
    },
    "-KTYWvZG466ADFRR667": {
      "username": "someone",
      "useremail": "hello2@kondedath.com",
      "password" : "hello1234"
      "userpic": "example.com/b.png",
      "prevelidge" : "normal"
    }
  }
}

Provide a user to input username( unique) and password and search through database to see if username and password matches and check his/her prevelidge and redirect to particular activity appropriately.

eg 
mFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://yourapp.firebaseio.com/").child("users")

Use above database reference to search users. You can also use the same to add new user. When adding a new user, give them default prevelidge.

This model fits well for less userbase like 20.

For more user bases( thousands, millions) you can use google authentication and use the User UID returned and create a new entry in your database(users).

Hope this helps you.